# Retrieve body of exchange object which is a map in Apache Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

```
Map<String,String> map= new HashMap<>();
map.put("simpletext","Simple text");
map.put("errortext","Error text");
exchange.getIn().setBody(map);
```

Based on the key of the map in the exchange object I want to write them to two separate file locations. How can I achieve this in apache camel?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the split EIP to send each map entry to a distinct file.
For instance:

```
.split(simple("${in.body.entrySet}"))
      .setHeader("theKey", simple("${body.getKey}"))
      .setBody(simple("${body.getValue}"))
      .process( e -> this.setTargetFileName(e) )
      .to("file:/mydir")
   .end()
   
   
private void setTargetFileName(Exchange exchange) {
  String key = exchange.getMessage().getHeader("theKey", String.class);
  if ( "simpletext".equals(key) ) {
    exchange.getMessage().setHeader("CamelFileName", "targetA.txt");
  } else {
    exchange.getMessage().setHeader("CamelFileName", "targetB.txt");
  }     
}
```

Comment: I want to use an if-else condition in my route that if the key is "simpletext" then send to abc file location, else if the key is "errortext" then send the file to xyz location.

Comment: You can introduce a `Processor` for such if-then-else logic. I have updated my answer